# Xamarin.Forms Call to message center increases in number each time

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-storage, messagingcenter

I've a problem where I send message once and Subscriber is called once but next time it is called twice and so on... Here's my code.
This is message sender

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;

        string downloadURL = taskSnapShot.DownloadUrl.ToString();
        string fileName = taskSnapShot.Metadata.Name;

        GBPaperReceipt.Model.ImageFile imageFile = new Model.ImageFile
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FilePath = downloadURL
        };
        MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, MessageStrings.ImageUploadEvent, imageFile);

        //save this live storage image url in receipt table

        //MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string>((Xamarin.Forms.Application)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, ChatModuleConstant.UploadMediaEvent, downloadURL);
    }
```

This is message receiver

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, ImageFile>((App)Application.Current, MessageStrings.ImageUploadEvent,async (a, imageFile) =>
        {
            _viewModel.Receipt.ImagePath = imageFile.FilePath;
            _viewModel.Receipt.ImageName = imageFile.FileName;
            try
            {
                await DependencyService.Get<IReceiptService>().SaveReceipt(_viewModel.Receipt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert(
                            "Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
            }


            DependencyService.Get<ICamera>().DeletePhoto(_viewModel._imageToBeDeletedOnSaveCommand);
            Dialogs.HideLoading();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DashboardPage());
        });
```

Unsubscription

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, string>((App)Application.Current, MessageStrings.ErrorEvent);
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, string>((App)Application.Current, MessageStrings.ImageUploadEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the Subscribe?

Comment: I am calling it in the on appearing function of my page.

Comment: Then that is why. Each time your page is shown you subscribe again.

Comment: I Unscribe at onDisappearing() let me edit the post.

Comment: I found the solution... I wasn't unsubscribing with the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when using your page inside a navigationpage, your subscription event will be added whenever the page comes into view. If you navigate back and forward a couple of times, your subscription to the messagingcenter will be added several times causing your event to double fire.

The safest way is to subscribe in the page constructor and even in that case it can be necessary to unsubscribefirst and then subscribe.

Your Appearing/Disappearing approach might work as well, however I am not entirely sure if the Appearing/Disappearing methods give you any guarantee to fire.

However, you also might try moving your unsubscriptions in front of base.OnDisappearing(), since you should unsubscribe before calling the base class to do the internal dismantling of your page.

If that doesn't work, subscribe in the constructor.

Comment: I found the solution... I wasn't unsubscribing with the same data type.